# Ruby - create methods with a dynamic names in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Maybe it's not wise question... but I have a one.
I was playing with Ruby and tried to create methods with a dynamic names in a loop, like this:

```
class Test

    .....
    class methods 
    .....

    for i in 1..100
       def method_#{i}
          my_hash[:test].first[i]
       end
    end
end
```

I noticed that's impossible, so... Is there any solution using a `:define_method`, or `:send` to solve my problem and gets methods like:
`method_0, method_1, method_2` etc. which return `my_hash[:test].first[1], my_hash[:test].first[2]` etc. ?

Comment: You mentioned `define_method`, did you try using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using `define_method`. Here is the code:

```
class Test
    .....
    class methods 
    .....

    1.upto(100) do |num|
        define_method("method_#{num}") do
            my_hash[:test].first[num]
        end
    end
end
```